# Multiple push notification in iphone

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Some time my iPhone shows me notification with message "You have 5 WhatsApp notfication".I know iPhone must combine all notification and shows this message.Is it documented anywhere ?

Comment: This is definitely something the server handles and not iOS.

Comment: I believe that it is part of WhatsApp. Flow should be something like this: Server sends VOIP or silent push notifications; app handles them and schedules Local notifications. App has full control over Local notifications, so it can cancel any previous Local notifications and then to schedule a new one with message like above.

Comment: I am working on chat app. IPhone does the same in case of my app too. I am sure we are not doing anything like you mentioned above.